# Context api useContext is not updating, always returning null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-context

I've go my context,

```
export const LocationContext = createContext(null);
export const LocationProvider = LocationContext.Provider;
export const useLocationContext = () => useContext(LocationContext);
```

Provider,

```
export const Search = () => {
    const [ location, setLocation ] = useState(null)
    
    const handleLocateMe = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            setLocation( { lat: position.coords.latitude, lon: position.coords.longitude} )
        });
    }

    return(
        <LocationProvider value={{location}}>
            <MapUISearch />
            <MapUIBtn _iconName={SmileOutlined} _type="primary" _className={styles.locateMe} _fn={()=> {handleLocateMe()}} />
        </LocationProvider>
    )
}
```

useContext,

```
const { location } = useLocationContext();
```

Issue is it always throws
*Cannot destructure property `location` of 'undefined' or 'null'.*

and useLocationContext is never gets updated and returns the default value of null

FYI: I've got same implementation for another context, which works as expected

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at this part of the documentation? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

Comment: @Unigazer thanks. It was not the problem but your comment helped me to figure the real prob :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally forgot that provider has to be on the higher (parent) component. My provider sat on the child component. Just had to change the provider to parent component and useContext to child components.